# looking for a pattern in ruby for matching string

Tags: ruby, regex

```
name="(this is 
a message
)

(other message)";

res=name.scan(/(\(.*\))/m);
puts res.join("###");
```

In the above code,I want to extract the matched parenthesis with the text inside the it as a whole expresstion.

I mean I want to get the following result through my code:

```
(this is 
a message
)###(other message)
```

That's to say,the length of the res should be 2 not 1,
But in my code,I always get:

```
(this is 
a message
)
(other message)
```

There must be something wrong with my pattern,can any one help me to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use a [non-greedy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Lazy_quantification) match, so change the regexp line to:

```
res=name.scan(/(\(.*?\))/m);
```